# Compare value from tables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am editing my codebehind file, and in the database I have this 4 tables linked together:

```
Table :Compannies
--------------------
companyId
--------------------
companyName
--------------------
```

And:

```
Table :UserCompany
--------------------
userId
--------------------
companyId
--------------------
```

And:

```
Table :Users
--------------------
UserId
--------------------
Email
--------------------
```

And:

```
Table :Choice
--------------------
Email
--------------------
Choice
--------------------
```

Now, I want to check all the companyName if the Choice accordingly = "YES" then do the action.

```
string sqlIns = "SELECT companyName FROM Companies WHERE companyId IN
                  (SELECT companyId FROM UserCompany WHERE userId IN 
                   (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Email IN 
                    (SELECT Email FROM Choice WHERE Choice='YES')"

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
                    conn.Open();
try
{
    SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlIns, conn);    
    if (cmdIns.Parameters.compareValue("currentCompanyName", companyName))//how to compare?
    {
         //action here
    }
    else
    {
         //another action
    }

    cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmdIns.Parameters.Clear();
    cmdIns.Dispose();
    cmdIns = null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      throw new Exception(ex.ToString(), ex);
}
finally
{
      conn.Close();
}
```

I don't know how to compare the value that extract from the tables, and is there any grammar or logic error in my code?

Comment: But there is no parameter defined in your `SqlCommand`?

Comment: what is *cmdIns.Parameters.compareValue()* method? i don't think it exists. and your question is not clear.

Comment: It seems you want to compare the result with another companyname?

Comment: Yes, it's correct ! I want to get only company name where its "choice" = "YES"

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, the " cmdIns.Parameters.compareValue()" may not exist, I just don't know how make the condition IF there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `inner-join` instead of nested queries:

Here is changed query:

```
SELECT cn.companyName from companies cn 
INNER JOIN UserCompany uc ON uc.companyid = cn.companyid 
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.userId = uc.userId
INNER JOIN Choice c ON c.Email = u.Email And c.Choice = @Choice
WHERE cn.CompanyName = @CompanyName;
```

Example code would be like that:

```
string commandText = @"SELECT cn.companyId, cn.companyName from companies cn 
                       INNER JOIN UserCompany uc ON uc.companyid = cn.companyid 
                       INNER JOIN Users u ON u.userId = uc.userId
                       INNER JOIN Choice c ON c.Email = u.Email And c.Choice = @Choice
                       WHERE cn.CompanyName = @CompanyName;";

string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"];

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);        

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Choice", "YES");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", "currentCompanyName");

    try
    {
        connection.Open();            

        datagridview.DataSource = command.ExecuteReader();
        datagridview.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       //handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I use that inner-joint to get all companyId where Choice = YES ?

Comment: You can use both `SELECT cn.companyId, cn.companyName` or any one of them in the query. try it

Comment: I mean in the code above, should I change where cn.CompanyName=@CompanyName by where c.Choice = 'YES' ? it doesn't return correctly.

Comment: No you don't have to change in the query. For variables preceding with `@` symbol, you are supplying value in the parameters. See `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` here you give values to @ parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I get confusing here. So after SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection); and command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Choice", "YES"); What do I get. It looks like it will add value YES to the table Choice. But what I need here will be get the companyID where Choice="YES" then I will delete the row with that companyId from the datagrid in my other question.