# How remove records from datagrid in asp.net if condition satisfy

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a datagrid declare like this in ascx file:

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgCompanies" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyField="companyId" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="True" AllowCustomPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanged="dgCompanies_Paging" Runat="server" onprerender="dgCompanies_PreRender" >
```

basically, datagrid is the search result some how like this in codebehind:

```
// retrieve the matching company records
        IDataReader rdr = Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Companies.Companies.ListCompanies(dgCompanies.CurrentPageIndex, pageSize, CompanyList, CompanyNameStartsWith, ProcessSqlClause, SkillSqlClause, LocationClause, KeywordSqlClause, User, Status, SearchPortalId, false, sortColumn, sortDirection);

        // highlight the sorted column
        highlightSortColumn();

        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            // calculate page details
            _count = (int) rdr["companyCount"];

            this.dgCompanies.VirtualItemCount = _count;


            // move onto the next resultset
            rdr.NextResult();

            // bind the data to the datagrid
            dgCompanies.PageSize = pageSize;
            dgCompanies.DataSource = rdr;
            dgCompanies.DataBind();
```

I will need to check if companyId is not equal to some values, then I need to remove that record from the search result, meaning remove it from that dgCompanies datagrid. I really have no idea I could do that, could anyone please give me some help here?

Comment: Why don't you populate reader accordingly?

Comment: it is a good suggestion but I don't know how to modify that reader! My understanding is the reader already fix in this command: IDataReader rdr = Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Companies.Companies.ListCompanies(dgCompanies.CurrentPageIndex, pageSize, CompanyList, CompanyNameStartsWith, ProcessSqlClause, SkillSqlClause, LocationClause, KeywordSqlClause, User, Status, SearchPortalId, false, sortColumn, sortDirection); and I can make no change to that?

Comment: OK let me specify in the answer

Comment: It is difficult to modify the query. I think it is happening in `ListCompanies` class you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to populate datareader based on required criteria.

In case you want to filter records from datareader, you can load it into `datatable`.

```
IDataReader rdr = Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Companies.Companies.ListCompanies(dgCompanies.CurrentPageIndex, pageSize, CompanyList, CompanyNameStartsWith, ProcessSqlClause, SkillSqlClause, LocationClause, KeywordSqlClause, User, Status, SearchPortalId, false, sortColumn, sortDirection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rdr);
rdr.Close();


for(int i = dt.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

   int iCompanyId = Convert.ToInt(dr["CompanyId"]);

   if (IsCompanyHavingChoiceYes(iCompanyId))
    dr.Delete();
}   


dt.AcceptChanges();

dgCompanies.PageSize = pageSize;
dgCompanies.DataSource = dt;  //provide datatable as datasource
dgCompanies.DataBind();
```

Method to check from database:

```
private  bool IsCompanyHavingChoiceYes(int iCompanyId)
    {            
        string commandText = @"SELECT cn.companyId from companies cn 
                   INNER JOIN UserCompany uc ON uc.companyid = cn.companyid 
                   INNER JOIN Users u ON u.userId = uc.userId
                   INNER JOIN Choice c ON c.Email = u.Email And c.Choice = @Choice
                   WHERE cn.CompanyId = @CompanyId;";

        string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"];

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyId", iCompanyId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Choice", "YES");

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    return reader.HasRows;
                }

                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPy3A.png

Comment: How could I remove rows that have companyId =  (SELECT companyId FROM UserCompany WHERE userId IN 
                   (SELECT UserId FROM Users WHERE Email IN 
                    (SELECT Email FROM Choice WHERE Choice='YES')"

Comment: I think nested queries not possible in both `datatable` and `dataview.Filter` experession. You have to fix your query for datareader.

Comment: Do you mean I need to do it in :IDataReader rdr = Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Companies.Companies.ListCompanies(dgCompanies.CurrentPageIndex, pageSize, CompanyList, CompanyNameStartsWith, ProcessSqlClause, SkillSqlClause, LocationClause, KeywordSqlClause, User, Status, SearchPortalId, false, sortColumn, sortDirection); I cannot change anything here because no source code.

Comment: I dont get the idea why I cannot change it in datatable ? The query can be execute this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671575/compare-value-from-tables-in-asp-net

Comment: Do I need to change the line highlightSortColumn() and if (rdr.Read()) accordingly if I use your code ?

Comment: I am not clear about `highlightSortColumn()`. Your question doesn't explain much about it. About above solution you can implement it in your other question you mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, but in original code it has "if (rdr.Read()).." and "rdr.NextResult(); " to move to next result, then apply datasource and bind data to dgCompanies. Now we change to datatable, how we change that two line related to rdr to dt datatable ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54104/discussion-between-hassan-nisar-and-user1314404).

Comment: I think the query is not working right. I tested and it with the testing data but its not giving right result.

Comment: What are you getting duplicate records or what?

Comment: It doesn't show error but also does not find the company although the name is there. When I try that query in SQL server management studio it said : I have collation conflict .. Is this the reason ?

Comment: I fixed the collation. Here is the error if I use the suggested method: Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'companyId'.

Comment: If there is a way to remove or hide the rows in datagrid dgCompanies it will be more more convenient coz now I can get companyName easily from datagrid. If using your datatable, I don't know how could I get the companyName.

Comment: Hi Hassan, I wonder why your command dt.Load(rdr); cannot load everything from rdr ? Because I got this error: Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'companyId'. Looks like rdr have this property but dt table doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly filter the `IDataReader` since it will be read like one by one.

What you can simply do is load all the data from datareader into `DataTable` using a <kbd>[**Load()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx)</kbd> method.

```
IDataReader rdr = Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Companies.Companies.
                  ListCompanies(dgCompanies.CurrentPageIndex, pageSize, CompanyList,
                  CompanyNameStartsWith, ProcessSqlClause, SkillSqlClause, 
                  LocationClause, KeywordSqlClause, User, Status, SearchPortalId, false, 
                  sortColumn, sortDirection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.(rdr);
//For filtering all the CompanyID column value not equal to  5
DataRow[] filteredRows=DataTable.Select("[CompanyID] <> 5 " ); 

dgCompanies.PageSize = pageSize;
dgCompanies.DataSource = filteredRows;
dgCompanies.DataBind();
```

Comment: There are many problem using this method. I think it is better if I can explain in chat session. How could I start chatting with you ?

Comment: The problem is if I use dt.Load(rdr); later I will get error: Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: companyCount at  Line 903:_count = (int) rdr["companyCount"];