# How extract text from datagrid in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

This is my datagrid view:

```
<a name="tagCompaniesDatagrid"></a>
        <asp:datagrid id="dgCompanies" Width="100%" ...
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="companyName" HeaderText="Company Name">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="40%" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="95%">
                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="LinkButton" id="btnView" Runat="server" CommandName="ViewDetails" CommandArgument="<%# GetViewUrl((System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)Container.DataItem) %>">
                                        <span ID="SpanTitle" Runat="server">
                                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"companyName") %>
                                        </span>
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="DGNormal" ID="lblStatus" Runat="server" text='<%# StatusToText((int) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"statusId")) %>'/>
                                    <asp:Image visible='<%# (bool) DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"WMCCMRated") %>' ID="imgProfiled" Runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/WMCCMRated.gif" AlternateText="This company has been competency profiled by WMG" />
                                    <asp:Image Visible='<%# !(Convert.IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"feedback")))%>' ID="feedback" Runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/feedback.gif" AlternateText="The number of feedback this company has been received is ->" ImageAlign="Bottom" Height="18px" Width="12px"/>
                                    <asp:Label CssClass="NormalBold" ID="lblFeedback" Runat="server" text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"feedback") %>' ForeColor="Navy"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormalBold">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"phoneNumber") %>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormal" ID="SpanProfile" Runat="server">
                                        <%# cutToNCharacters((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Profile")) %>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <cc1:DropDownCombo ID="dplCompanies" Runat="server" Width="95%" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyId" DataSource='<%# GetCompanyNames() %>' />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="address" HeaderText="Address">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormal" ID="SpanAddress" Runat="server">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"address")%>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="keyProcessList" HeaderText="Key Processes">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormal" ID="SpanKeyProcesses" Runat="server">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"keyProcessList") %>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="keySkillList" HeaderText="Key Skills">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="DGNormal" ID="SpanKeySkills" Runat="server">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"keySkillList") %>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                </ItemTemplate>
```

....

I want to get the companyName and I think it is store at the span ID="SpanTitle".
So I tried this:

```
int j = 0;
               foreach (DataGridItem item in dgCompanies.Items)
               {
                   Label name = (Label)item.Cells[j].FindControl("SpanTitle");

                 using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/DataTableRows.txt"), true))
                {
                    string drstring = Convert.ToString(name.Text);
                    _testData.WriteLine(drstring); // Write the file.
                }
                 j = j + 1;

             }
```

But I got error
 `"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'."`
How could I get the text of companyName from my datagrid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aspx markup `<span ID="SpanTitle" Runat="server">` is not `<asp:Label>`. So please cast it to `HtmlGenericControl` and get the InnerText

```
HtmlGenericControl name = (HtmlGenericControl)
                           item.Cells[j].FindControl("SpanTitle");

string drstring = name.InnerText.Trim(); // Trim to remove extra spaces
```

Comment: @user1314404, I updated my answer. Its a typo use `InnerHtml` or `InnerText`. InnerText would be appropriate

Comment: Thank you, you are right! But can I get the name without surrounding space? When I write to file I see a big space in front of the names. Is there any way I can get exact name only because I need to use that to query the database?

Comment: This is the short, precise and perfect answer! I would like to seek your help for my related question on this datagrid also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774851/how-remove-records-from-datagrid-in-asp-net-if-condition-satisfy/23775670?noredirect=1#comment36571514_23775670

Comment: @user1314404, added the answer. check it and let me know what error you get now